# Vimeo PHP SDK - how set the title/description?

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

After the upload, how I set the title / description of the video in Vimeo using PHP ?

```
$uri = $lib->upload($localfile);
$video_data = $lib->request($uri);
if ($uri)
{
    $link = $video_data['body']['link'];
    $lib->request($uri, array('name' => 'Teste','description' => 'My upload by vimeo php api'), 'PATCH');
    echo "<br>Success $filename was sent to $link ";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call:

```
$lib->request($uri, array(
             'name' => 'name of video',
             'description' => 'description'
             ), 'PATCH');
```

Make sure your token has *edit* scope enabled.

More about scopes: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#supported-scopes

Comment: Thanks a lot, really my token was not able to edit.
I created a new one